# How to set up scripts in to a Choice Menu with Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm building a menu with this command `CHOICE /c 123456789 /N /M "Type your choise"`

This is inside a my menu batch script and it calls Tools1.bat it makes everything inside the Tools.bat run with Sub folder reader

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D') Do @PushD "%%G" && (Call "%~dp0Tools1.bat" >NUL 2>&1 & PopD)
)
```

Tools.bat

```
ren "asset_database_?_*_?_Release" Asset_Database_Cleaned_0.txt
findstr /i "icon" Asset_Database_Cleaned_0.txt > Asset_Database_Cleaned_1.txt
findstr /i "[(0-9)]" Asset_Database_Cleaned_0.txt > Asset_Database_Cleaned_2.txt
ren "Asset_Database_Cleaned_0.txt" asset_database_9_99_9_Release

ren "%~dp01_Prior_Version\Asset_Database_Cleaned_2.txt" "Prior Version.txt"
ren "%~dp02_Current_Version\Asset_Database_Cleaned_2.txt" "Current Version.txt"
)
```

I have 2 folders with one file inside each folder

```
01_Prior_Version
 + -- asset_database_2_09_7_Release
02_Current_Version
 + -- asset_database_3_29_4_Release
```

the asset_database has random numbers so I use wildcards for that 
asset_database*Release or asset_database_?_*_?_Release

These files get renamed to Asset_Database_Cleaned_0.txt 
and then I use `findstr /i` to extract content that I need

I have tried many different ways to add that top script to my menu batch script

I have tried many different ways to add a Sub folder reader using `SET & Source` etc

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
@For %%G In ("%~dp01_Prior_Version") Do Set "source=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp02_Prior_Version") Do Set "target=%%~fG"

Set "Source1=1_Prior_Version\Asset_Database_Cleaned_1.txt"
Set "Target1=1_Prior_Version\Prior Version.txt"

    findstr /i "icon [(0-9)]" %Source1% > %Target1%
    ren "Prior\Asset_Database_Cleaned_0.txt" asset_database_9_99_9_Release
```

I tried using this script, but couldn't put all of that above together

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%i in ('dir /b/s/a-d') DO (
  if "%%~xi" == "" rename "%%~fi" "%%~ni.txt"
)
```

This is my menu

```
:Data Finder
echo.
ECHO ################################################################
ECHO            ALL YOUR ORIGINAL FILES WILL BE SAVED
ECHO ################################################################
echo.
ECHO                Press 1 - Extract Data
ECHO                Press 2 - Run PY
echo.
ECHO                   Thank You
ECHO               For all the support
echo.


CHOICE /c 123456789 /N /M "Type your choise"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D') Do @PushD "%%G" && (Call "%~dp0Tools1.bat" >NUL 2>&1 & PopD)
goto=:Data Finder
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 (
Call "%~dp0Tools2.py"
goto=:Data Finder
)
```

When I add this in, the CMD just closes

Comment: What's `goto=:Data Finder`? Are you sure about the `=`? The `:` is not necessary. If you have executed an `@error off` command,  the `@` in `@command` is superfluous.

Comment: @Magoo - Thanks it the `= and :` still work with it, but I will update it, so in `@For /F` and `@For %%G In` are wrong so I will remove them, now the script `WITH THIS` what is the best way yo make all of that work with this `('Dir /B /S /A:D') `